# google map query string format for addresses instead of lat/long?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am developing an android application for which I am using latitude/longitude to draw a map

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=47.295601,0.010586&daddr=47.295601,1.010586
+t‌​o:47.295601,2.010586+to:47.295601,3.010586+to:42.223501,2.011586
+to:35.215621,1.020456
```

but now I want to draw the map through addresses instead of latitude/Longitude. I googled but not found any such help for query string to Draw map from addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the same thing but separate each part of the address with commas.

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=47.295601,0.010586
&daddr=123 Main Street, Houston, Texas, 77707
+t‌​o:47.295601,2.010586
+to:321 Avenue A, Baton Rouge, Lousiana, 68594
+to:42.223501,2.011586
+to:35.215621,1.020456
```

You may use a combination of coordinates and addresses.

Comment: Normally when I program for Android the start address will be the coordinate you receive with the users current location from the Location Manager.  The rest of the address will usually be in address form from something stored in the database or entered by the user.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like http://maps.google.com/maps?q=from:champs+elysees,+paris+to:+toulouse+to:Marseille

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use the Geocoder to receive the LatLng values?

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> adr = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationName, maxResults);
```